# How to disable items in CheckBoxList from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a `CheckBoxList` with 5 fixed items. When the first item is checked, I want the rest to be disabled - client side only.

Could you help me with that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nextAll and do (this assumes jquery version > 1.6):

```
<div id='check'>
    <input type='checkbox' >
    <input type='checkbox' >
    <input type='checkbox' >
    <input type='checkbox' >
    <input type='checkbox' >
</div>

$('#check input:checkbox:first').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $(this).nextAll('input:checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $(this).nextAll('input:checkbox').removeProp('disabled');
    }
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/QpAz6/

Answer (score 0):

have you consider using 5 `CheckBox` controls ....